# When I use tkinter to create a window as a decorator to decorate another tk window, setting the `font` causes control to occasionally not display text

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, decorator

I created a decorator `wrap_tk` so that when the decorated function `tk_clock` runs, a tkinter window appears to indicate that the task is running, and is automatically destroyed when the decorated function finishes running.

But when I run the script, the results are erratic:

- The tkinter window generated by the decorator sometimes does not display any text.
- Another problem arises when this window displays text: When I close the tkinter window generated by the decorated function, the python interpreter does not exit completely

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import time, threading, datetime


#%%
def wrap_tk(tkstr="warp_tkwindow"):
    def do_tkwindows(func):
        def make_tk(t1):
            wrap_tk_root = tk.Tk()
            timestr = tk.StringVar()
            timestr.set(
                "==={}:{}s===".format(
                    tkstr, round(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - t1, 2)
                )
            )
            
            wrap_tk_fontExample = tkFont.Font(size=16)
            wrap_tk_lb = tk.Label(
                wrap_tk_root, textvariable=timestr, font=wrap_tk_fontExample
            )
            wrap_tk_lb.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
            wrap_tk_root.mainloop()

        def show_tk(*args, **kwargs):

            wrap_tk_ntk = threading.Thread(
                target=make_tk, args=(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp(),)
            )
            wrap_tk_ntk.setDaemon(True)
            wrap_tk_ntk.start()

            rf = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return rf

        return show_tk

    return do_tkwindows

def tk_clock():
    def gettime():
        tk_clock_lb.config(text=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
        print(tk_clock_fontExample.config()["size"]) # lol
        tk_clock_root.after(100, gettime)

    tk_clock_root = tk.Tk()
    tk_clock_fontExample = tkFont.Font(size=16)
    tk_clock_lb = tk.Label(
        tk_clock_root, text="%H:%M:%S", font=tk_clock_fontExample
    )
    tk_clock_lb.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

    gettime()
    tk_clock_root.mainloop()


#%%

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wrap_tk(tkstr="xxx")(tk_clock)() 
    print("all down")
```

I did some testing and found that this was due to the font parameter in the Label.As long as I don't set this parameter there is no problem. I feel very strange, can anyone tell me what this is about?

Comment: I would encourage you to not use threads here. It makes the code more complicated than it needs to be. Search this site for questions related to timers, clocks, and the `after` method. Accessing tkinter widgets from a separate thread doesn't always work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I want to use this decorator to provide a working status indication for some time-consuming computational tasks. It works well on other tasks. Using threading to start another thread is simply an attempt to not interfere with the execution of other tasks. I think it's more logically clear. But when I use it to decorate another tk window, this problem occurs. This confused me.